# How can I copy songs from an iPod to a Mac without using iTunes?

Tags: itunes, mac, ipod-touch

my friend has an iPod Touch and she cannot use it with iTunes anymore.

is it possible to save those songs somehow on another computer and then reset iPod and copy songs back? or in general have a backup on a computer?

Comment: Why can't she use it with iTunes any longer?

Comment: You can use iTunes even if the device is JailBroken. Why can't she use it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Senuti](http://www.fadingred.com/senuti/) is the tool of choice in these situations:

> Need to recover music, playlists, or videos from your iPod or iPhone? Look no further! With Senuti, you can recreate your iTunes music library in just one click.
>
> Want to be more specific? Preview and select only the songs and playlists you want to transfer. Senuti has helped millions around the world recover their music, videos, and playlists since 2004.